# Rails Autocomplete Jquery (crowdint): select .uniq not working in scope, avoiding duplicates

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, duplicates

Companies can be autocompleted by looking up the entries which I already have.
Using the https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem, I have added

```
autocomplete :company, :name, :scopes => [:distinct]
```

to my controller and in my model I have:

```
scope :distinct, lambda { select("companies.name").uniq }
```

Using the term "Merce" my system still returns all 5 entries for Mercedes Benz. SQL:

```
35mCompany Load (4.0ms)[0m  SELECT DISTINCT companies.name, companies.id FROM "companies" WHERE (LOWER(companies.name) ILIKE 'merce%') ORDER BY companies.name ASC LIMIT 10
```

Various things I tried:

```
select(:name).uniq  => Not unique values
distinct("companies.name") => Wrong number of arguments
group(:id, :name) => Not unique values
group(:id, :name).uniq  => Not unique values
```

However, using the select statement in the controller (without autocomplete) works:

```
@companies = Company.select(:name).uniq => Perfect results
```

Looking for an explanation as to how to make the correct query within this gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query that is generated by that gem:

```
Company Load (4.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT companies.name, companies.id FROM "companies" WHERE (LOWER(companies.name) ILIKE 'merce%') ORDER BY companies.name ASC LIMIT 10
```

Will always include the table primary id plus the name of the field(s) that will be auto-completed, the answer to that lies in [lines 36 and 37 of this method](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/orm/active_record.rb#L36):

```
def get_autocomplete_select_clause(model, method, options)
  table_name = model.table_name
  (["#{table_name}.#{model.primary_key}", "#{table_name}.#{method}"] + (options[:extra_data].blank? ? [] : options[:extra_data]))
end
```

That query results are already unique (it uses the distinct name + id). I can think of two possible ways to work around this:

1. Create a query with a subquery, the idea would be to create a first query that returns unique results then outer join it with the table ids and that will return unique names with its ids.
2. In your controller redefine the action that retrieve the results so that it do whatever you want. Actually what this gem does is to add the autocomplete_model_attribute action to your controller using meta programming ([see source code](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb#L45)).

Hope this helps let me know if this helps. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation was absolutely correct, I then went with the second route by redefining the controller. I will post my solution below for others to see.

Answer (score 4):

As Chischaschos above already said, redefining the controller action is the best course. Because I am using PostgreSQL on Heroku, I needed to go for a more complex route developed by Thuss (Thodd Huss):

> When I want custom autocompletion that goes beyond the features of
>   the current plugin (such as selecting distinct entities) I implement
>   my own autocomplete method on the controller. This just replaces the
>   "autocomplete :organization, :city" call you would normally put in
>   your controller.
>   For example to autocomplete "distinct" cities I do this:

```
def autocomplete_organization_city
 term = params[:term]
 if term && !term.empty?
  items = Organization.select("distinct city").
      where("LOWER(city) like ?", term.downcase + '%').
      limit(10).order(:city)
 else
 items = {}
 end
render :json => json_for_autocomplete(items, :city)
end
```

There is also a shorter solution for users on SQLite, which is much shorter. Find the orginial thread here:
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/issues/25

Answer (score 2):

Better approach:

```
  # model
  scope :distinct_on_name, lambda {
      select('DISTINCT ON (models.name) models.name, models.id')
  }
  # controller
  autocomplete :model, :name, scopes: [:distinct_on_name]
```